# Node.js date incorrect coming from React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

If I console log the date in Node I get the correct date:

```
console.log(`Date according to Node: ${new Date()}`);
```

> Date according to Node: Mon Apr 04 2022 17:52:20 GMT+0200

However, when I send the date from React via a POST request and console log that date from the `req.body` I get:

> 2022-04-03T22:00:00.000Z

even though when logging the date from the date picker in react to console, I get the correct date! The date I get in console (React) is:

> Mon Apr 04 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200

So, what happens in between that makes `req.body.myDate` give me the incorrect date? I can see that my React date has no time, but not sure if that makes a difference in this case.

React:

```
  const onSubmit = async (data, e) => {
    var d = new Date(data.visitDate);
    d = new Date(
      `${d.getFullYear()}-${String(101 + d.getMonth()).substr(1)}-${String(
        100 + d.getDate()
      ).substr(1)}`
    );
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/endpoint",
        {
          email: email,
          apptDate: d,
        }
      );
      if (response.status === 201) {
        setSuccess(true);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setSuccess(false);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that React serializes the date using `.toISOString()` when constructing the POST request, and that always gives a date in UTC (with the `Z` suffix). Note that `2022-04-03T22:00:00.000Z` is the same point in time as `2022-04-04T00:00:00.000+02:00`.

If you want a point in time at UTC midnight, you must ensure that you create the Javascript `Date` as such, e.g., as `new Date("2022-04-04")`. By contrast, `new Date()` creates a Date in your browser's timezone:

```js
new Date("2022-04-04").toISOString() === '2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z'
new Date().toISOString() === '2022-04-03T22:00:00.000Z'
```

if you execute both statements at midnight in your timezone.

To get the current date in React, you can use:

```js
var d=new Date();
new Date(`${d.getFullYear()
  }-${String(101+d.getMonth()).substr(1)
  }-${String(100+d.getDate()).substr(1)
  }`).toISOString()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, do I need to do something different on the react side or the Node.js side? The date is from a date picker ie: user input `email: data.email, apptDate: data.apptDate`

Comment: Try my last code snippet in React.

Comment: So, it seems to work for getting the date today and now etc. but not with the date picker input. I have tried to set d to `data.apptDate` ie `var d=data.apptDate` but I get the same issue with it showing yesterday's date in Node.js

Comment: Can you share the relevant React Javascript code?

Comment: I have updated my question with the React code

Comment: Does it work with the change I made to your code?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! However, my code editor is suggesting that using `substr` like this is deprecated?

Comment: After some searching I have discovered that this is a React Date Picker bug and one of the favoured solutions is `const offsetDate = new Date(data.visitDate.getTime() - data.visitDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);`